# iOS 8 Extensions - File Provider

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

Im currently looking at how to share data such as photos or documents between apps and have came up with a few ways to do it. Using custom pasteboards and storing the information in keychain and providing access from both apps. However, I'm wondering if there is a way to do it with the file provider extension.

So far i've seen that its more driven towards cloud storage platforms such as iCloud Drive, Google Drive etc. My Question is can i make my first app a document provider? And then from the second app use the document provider in the first app to create, update delete documents.

This technology is obviously quite new and i am finding it hard to get information on the topic.